# How do I add odd/even class only for table rows which haven´t had odd/even class yet?

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

How do I add odd/even class only for table rows which haven´t had odd/even class yet?
(for some tables I use PHP cycle function).

Is this correct?

```
$("table tbody tr td")
  .parent("tr:nth-child(odd):not(.odd)")
  .addClass("odd")
  .end()
  .parent("tr:nth-child(even):not(.even)")
  .addClass("even");
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will not duplicate the class if it has already been defined. You can of course always check using `.hasClass()` but it is not necessary in this scenario.

Try:

```
$("table tbody tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
$("table tbody tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
```

[Edit]: From your question is seems that *some*, but not all, rows have the "odd" or "even" classes already added to them. The safest way is to strip all classes and add them back using JS - `$("table tbody tr").removeClass("odd even")`

Answer (score 0):

Why can not use as follows?

```
$("table tbody tr:odd").addClass("odd");
$("table tbody tr:even").addClass("even");
```