# jquery equal to PHP <?=++$r%2?'odd':'even'?> for striped table rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, tablerow

I do this in PHP: `++$r%2?'odd':'even'` in order to apply striped rows..

```
<tr class="<?=++$r%2?'odd':'even'?>"><td>...</td></tr>
```

But when I get the recordset trough an `$.ajax`-request, I return the result like this:

```
$('#table_selected tbody').empty();  //  empty the table
$.ajax({  //  fetch new data and insert into new rows
    ...
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i, array){
            $('#table_selected tbody').append('<tr><td>'+array['name']+'</td></tr>');
        });
    }
});
```

What I would like to do is to add the `odd`/`even`-class to the `<tr>`-element on every other row - like I do in php.

Is there a similar way to achieve this in js/jqyery?

I read this answer: [How do I add odd/even class only for table rows which haven´t had odd/even class yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387441/how-do-i-add-odd-even-class-only-for-table-rows-which-havent-had-odd-even-class), and I think that's a start on what I want to achieve, but not sure how to work the solution into my code:

```
$("table tbody tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
$("table tbody tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
```

Comment: `$("#table_selected tbody tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd"); $("#table_selected tbody tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");` after the each loop

Comment: What are the `odd` and `even` classes used for? If it's purely styling there's probably a CSS-only solution for it that would eliminate the need for the PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: There is a CSS only way of doing this but it does not work in IE8 or lower.  e.g. in the CSS put tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#333;}

Comment: It is purely for applying different styling for each row..

And that was so easy that I'm embarrassed.. I was thinking in the wrong direction... Thanks @Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly just need to stripe the tables odd/even rows, could you not just add this to your css for the page:

```
#table_selected tbody tr:nth-child(odd){ background-color: green; }
#table_selected tbody tr:nth-child(even){ background-color: yellow; }
```

If you need the classes, as Arun P Johny suggests in the comments, you update your script like this:

```
$('#table_selected tbody').empty();  //  empty the table
$.ajax({  //  fetch new data and insert into new rows
    ...
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i, array){
            $('#table_selected tbody').append('<tr><td>'+array['name']+'</td></tr>');
        });

        $("#table_selected tbody tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
        $("#table_selected tbody tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
    }
});
```

or like this (more analogous to your php way):

```
$('#table_selected tbody').empty();  //  empty the table
$.ajax({  //  fetch new data and insert into new rows
    ...
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i, array){
            $('#table_selected tbody').append(
                $('<tr><td>' + array['name'] + '</td></tr>')
                    .addClass(i % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even')
            );
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The second solution you provided adds the class only to the `table tbody` itself. But I used the `(i % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even')` like this instead: `<tr class="'+(i%2?'even':'odd')+'">`.